# roll-up record, max of each column, group_by R

Tags: r, group-by, max

This seems fairly simple, and I have a solution, but it's kinda time consuming since I have a lot of columns. I have looked at other solutions, but it's always been for something slightly different (aggregate one column, mutate all columns etc). In SQL I would do `select PAT_ID, max(X), max(Y), max(Z) from table_name group by PAT_ID`.

I have a data set that looks like this (but with more columns):

```
dt <- data.frame(
  PAT_ID = c('P','P','P','A','A','A'),
  X = c(1,NA,NA, 1,NA,NA),
  Y = c(NA,2,NA,NA,1,NA),
  Z = c(NA,NA,1,NA,NA,0)
)
```

So I summarize and then combine the results:

```
results_X  <-dt %>%                              
  group_by(PAT_ID ) %>%                        
  summarise(X = max(X, na.rm=TRUE)) 

results_Y  <-dt %>%                             
  group_by(PAT_ID ) %>%                       
  summarise(Y = max(Y, na.rm=TRUE)) 

results_Z  <-dt %>%                             
  group_by(PAT_ID ) %>%                       
  summarise(Z = max(Z, na.rm=TRUE)) 

resulted <- left_join(results_X, results_Y )
resulted <- left_join(resulted, results_Z)
```

My output is the "roll-up" record that is the max value for each column per PAT_ID:

```
   myresult <- data.frame(
    PAT_ID = c('P','A'),
    X = c(1,1),
    Y = c(2,1),
    Z = c(1,0)
    )
```

I'm sure there's a better way to do this, but how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with a `summarize_all` in `dplyr`. Here you go

```
library(dplyr)
dt %>% group_by(PAT_ID) %>% summarize_all(max, na.rm=T)
#   PAT_ID     X     Y     Z
#   <fctr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1      A     1     1     0
# 2      P     1     2     1
```

Comment: summarise_each(funs(max(., na.rm = TRUE))) ... Thanks! I hadn't realized the summarise_each would not apply to the group by variable. Just noting a small edit to the syntax

Comment: @soporific Note the message on the `?summarise_each` help page: "In the future mutate_each() and summarise_each() will be deprecated in favour of a more featureful family of functions: mutate_all(), mutate_at(), mutate_if(), summarise_all(), summarise_at() and summarise_if()." That's why i've used `summarize_all()` here.

Comment: Oh thanks! I had to reinstall dplyr and restart my session to get those fns. New features! :)

Answer (score 1):

This can also be accomplished with base R using `aggregate`.

```
aggregate(dt[c("X","Y","Z")], dt["PAT_ID"], FUN=max, na.rm=TRUE)
  PAT_ID X Y Z
1      A 1 1 0
2      P 1 2 1
```